# Can't turn scraped data into csv file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-
diagnostic").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
products = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "product details product-item-details"})
for product in products:
    product_details = dict()
    product_details['name'] = product.find('a').text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['brand'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['packaging'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['availability'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'avail pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['price'] = product.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    print(product_details)

prod = product_details

with open('../../www/products.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', 'Price'])
    for product in products:
        writer.writerow([product['Name'], product['Brand'],product['Packaging'], product['Availability'], product['Price']])
```

Result:

```
{'name': 'Kimberly Clark Blue Nitrile Exam Gloves -100/BX', 'brand': 'Kimberly Clark', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nKimberly Clark', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$26.94'}
{'name': 'Pro Advantage Gloves - 200/BX', 'brand': 'Pro Advantage', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nPro Advantage', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$28.94'}
{'name': 'Kimberly Clark Powder Free Exam Gloves - 500/CS', 'brand': 'Kimberly Clark', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nKimberly Clark', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$136.99'}
{'name': 'Kimberly Clark Sterile Pairs Exam Gloves - 400/CS', 'brand': 'Kimberly Clark', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nKimberly Clark', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$205.99'}
{'name': 'Dynarex Multi Care Vinyl Exam Gloves Non-Latex - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nDynarex', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$61.99'}
{'name': 'Dynarex Tillotson Powder Free Plus Latex Exam Gloves - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nDynarex', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$109.99'}
{'name': 'Dynarex 6512 True Advantage High Risk Nitrile Exam Gloves, 8 mil - 500/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nDynarex', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$105.99'}
{'name': 'Dynarex 6512 True Advantage High Risk Nitrile Exam Gloves, 8 mil - 50/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nDynarex', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$20.99'}
{'name': 'Dynarex Tillotson Tru Advantage PF Nitrile Exam Gloves - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nDynarex', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$101.99'}
{'name': 'Dynarex Tillotson Tru Advantage PF Nitrile Exam Gloves - 100/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Brand: \n\nDynarex', 'availability': 'Availability: \n\n1-3 Days', 'price': '$18.99'}
```

---

```
KeyError

Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-668855af45c8> in <module>()
     24     writer.writerow(['Name', 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', 'Price'])
     25 for product in products:
---> 26     writer.writerow([product['Name'], product['Brand'],product['Packaging'], product['Availability'], product['Price']])
     27
     28

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1009         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
   1010         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
-> 1011         return self.attrs[key]
   1012
   1013     def __iter__(self):

KeyError: 'Name'
```

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe is should be `product['name']` **not** `product['Name']`. P.S. In the future, if you're going to ask questions here, please learn how to use markdown to format them properly—you'll be more likely to real and better answers if people can figure-out what it is you're asking...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but, the lower case was a no-go. :( Sorry, will do.

Comment: Oh well, I said it was just a guess. Suggest you `print(products)` right before the `for product in products:` line and see what's in it and make sure the keys are what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Martineau was right - `Name` should be chanded to `name` and similar changes should be done for every key in `product_details` dictionary.

But that's not the only issue here - your scraping won't work as you want because `product_details['packaging']` and `product_details['availability']` have newline chars in the middle of their strings. So they need to be cleaned as well.

Also in your current flow you won't get results because you're collecting every row data to `product_details` dictionary, but you're writing to `csv` from the `products` object (with all tags stuff). And you initially simply rewrite `product_details` on each iteration, and don't even use this dictionary to write to the output file.

So in writing loop you need to change `products` on `product_details`.

Here's a working scenario:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
products = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "product details product-item-details"})


with open('.../products.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(['Name' + '\t' + 'Brand' + '\t' + 'Packaging' + '\t' + 'Availability' + '\t' + 'Price'])
    for product in products:
        product_details = dict()
        product_details['name'] = product.find('a').text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['brand'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['packaging'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['availability'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'avail pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['price'] = product.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')

        product_details['packaging'] = product_details['packaging'][9:] # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Brand: \n\n"
        product_details['availability'] = product_details['availability'][16:] # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Availability: \n\n"
        writer.writerow([product_details['name'] + '\t' + product_details['brand'] + '\t' + product_details['packaging'] + '\t' + product_details['availability'] + '\t' + product_details['price']])
```

I changed the separator of `csv` file to `tab` because `name` of products in some cases contain commas, and for example for `excel` it will be a wrong char-separator of columns, so in some rows you would have an excess column.

Comment: @Jonathan, any feedback? was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

you have error in keyName which should be `lowercase` and in code below,

```
for product in products:
    writer.writerow......
```

`products` is `BeautifulSoup object` not list of your products that generated in previous loop and you can't use this for csv value.

last, you can try this solution

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
products = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "product details product-item-details"})
all_product = []

for product in products:
    product_details = dict()
    product_details['name'] = product.find('a').text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['brand'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['packaging'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['availability'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'avail pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['price'] = product.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    all_product.append(product_details)

print(all_product)

with open('products.csv', 'w+') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', 'Price'])
    for product in all_product:
        writer.writerow([product['name'], product['brand'],product['packaging'], product['availability'], product['price']])
```